# sort method List class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem, wherein, I need to sort only the odd numbers of an array (python list) and let the even numbers be.

My idea to progress through this problem:

1. filter out the odd and even numbers into separate lists.
2. sort the odd array and finally, extend it with the even array.

My Code:

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    # Return a sorted array.
    odd_arr = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, source_array))
    even_arr = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, source_array))

    return odd_arr.sort().extend(even_arr)
```

Issue faced: Python throws an `AttributeError`

Trace:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
 Test.assert_equals(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]), [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4])
File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 8, in sort_array
  return odd_arr.sort().extend(even_arr)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

now whenever I `print(odd_arr)` I get the list but when I `print(odd_arr.sort())` I get a `NoneType` object. I was under the impression that sort and extend were list class methods. Where am I going wrong? This has to be my own doing.

*EDIT:*
Changed code

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odds = [n for n in source_array if n % 2 != 0]
    evens = [n for n in source_array if n % 2 == 0]
    print(odds) # List
    print(evens) # List
    print(sorted(odds).extend(evens)) # None
    return sorted(odds).extend(evens)
```

Comment: Are you open to using 3rd party libraries (e.g. `numpy`)? Or are you looking to do this loopy?

Comment: I want to keep it vanilla, this will strengthen my understanding of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Methods of a mutable type generally mutate the object and return `None` instead of returning a modified object. Contrast this with methods of an immutable type (such as `str`) that *must* return a modified object.

Comment: doesn't `sort()` modify the list in place? What I understand from that is the it would return a sorted object, no?

Comment: @SaiBorg: "In place" and "returning the object" are two mutually-exclusive concepts in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. `list.sort` does an in-place sort and returns `None`. "pythonic" API's that modify an object generally don't return that object. Most programs wouldn't use that object so it would just be a pointless increment and decrement of the reference count. Use `sorted` instead

```
return sorted(odd_arr).extend(even_arr)
```

You can also ditch that `filter` and `lambda` stuff with generators

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    arr = sorted(x for x in source_array if not x % 2).extend(
        x for x in source_array if x % 2)
    return arr
```

Comment: sorted is still returning a NoneType! I believe there's a flaw in my understanding of the language and its very frustrating. I will edit my question above to show where I am.

Comment: That's my bad. I pasted an early version of my fix. It was returning the `None` from extend.